# Отсортировать список на PHP (не таблица)

Tags: сортировка, php

Доброго дня! Необходимо отсортировать список выводимых позиций по наименованию, либо как вариант прикрутить кнопку для сортировки. Хорошо есть такой код.

```
 <?
    if( !isset( $_COOKIE['compare'] ) || $_COOKIE['compare'] == '{}'){
        $compare_html = '<p class="no-compare">Не выбраны товары для сравнения</p>';
    }else{
        $data = json_decode($_COOKIE['compare'],true);
        $in_arr = implode(',',$data);

         $sql = "SELECT 
                `i`.`id` as `type_id`,
                `i`.`name` as `type_name`,
                `c`.`id` as `cat_id`,
                `c`.`name` as `cat_name`,
                `ci`.`id` as `item_id`,
                `jva`.`attr` as `attr_id`,
                `jva`.`name` as `attr_name`,
                `jva`.`value` as `attr_value`
            FROM `plug_cat_join_cat_item` as `ci`
            JOIN (
                SELECT `v`.`write_id`, `v`.`attr`, `v`.`value`, `a`.`name` FROM `plug_cat_vals` as `v`
                INNER JOIN `plug_cat_attr` as `a` ON `a`.`id` = `v`.`attr`
            ) `jva` ON `jva`.`write_id` = `ci`.`id`
            INNER JOIN `plug_cat_item` as `i` ON `i`.`id` = `ci`.`item`
            INNER JOIN `plug_cat_cat` as `c` ON `c`.`id` = `ci`.`cat`
            WHERE `ci`.`id` IN (".$in_arr.")
            ORDER BY `item_id`" 
        $itms = $db->GetTable($sql);
        $items = array();

        foreach ($itms as $item) {
            //$i = isset($items[$item['cat_id']]) ? sizeof($items[$item['cat_id']])+1 : 0;
            $items[$item['cat_id']][$item['item_id']]['id'] = $item['item_id'];
            $items[$item['cat_id']][$item['item_id']]['cat_id'] = $item['cat_id'];
            $items[$item['cat_id']][$item['item_id']]['cat_name'] = $item['cat_name'];
            if( $item['attr_id'] == 1 ){
                $items[$item['cat_id']][$item['item_id']]['item_name']  = ( $item['attr_value']!='' ) ? $item['attr_value'] : $item['type_name'];

            }  
            if( $item['attr_id'] == 3 ){
                $items[$item['cat_id']][$item['item_id']]['item_price']  = ( $item['attr_value']!='' ) ? $item['attr_value'].' руб.' : 'Не указано';
            } 
            if( $item['attr_id'] == 6 ){
                $items[$item['cat_id']][$item['item_id']]['item_image']  = ( $item['attr_value']!='' ) ? $item['attr_value'] : '/plugins/catalog/front/img/default.gif';
            }
            if( $item['attr_id'] > 11 )
                {
                    $items[$item['cat_id']][$item['item_id']]['attrs'][$item['attr_id']]['name'] = $item['attr_name'];

                    $items[$item['cat_id']][$item['item_id']]['attrs'][$item['attr_id']]['attr'] = $item['attr_id'];

                    $items[$item['cat_id']][$item['item_id']]['attrs'][$item['attr_id']]['value'] = $item['attr_value'];;

                }   
        }
            //$items = array_values($items);
        $compare_html = '<a class="compare_print" href="javascript:window.print()">Распечатать страницу</a>';
        foreach ($items as $cid => $itm) {
            $table = '<p class="compare_table_name">'.$itm[key($itm)]['cat_name'].'</p>
                    <table class="compare_table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Товар</th>
                                <th>Цена</th>';
            foreach ($itm[key($itm)]['attrs'] as $key => $value) {
                $table .='          <th>'.$value['name'].'</th>';
            }
            $table .='      </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>';
            $row = 1;
            foreach ($itm as $item) {
                $class = $row%2 == 0 ? 'odd' :'';
                $table .= '<tr class="'.$class.'">
                                <td class="item-column">
                                    <a class="item-link" href="'.$catalog->getItemURL($item['id']).'">
                                        <img src="'.$item['item_image'].'" width="100px" />
                                        <span>'.$item['item_name'].'</span>
                                        <a href="#" class="del-compare" onClick="delCompare('.$item['id'].');location.reload();">Убрать из сравнения</a>
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                                <td>'.$item['item_price'].'</td>';
                foreach ($item['attrs'] as $key => $value) {
                    $table .= '<td>'.$value['value'].'</td>';
                }
                $table .= '</tr>';
                $row++;
            }
            $table .= '</tbody>
                    </table>';
            $compare_html .= $table;
        }
    }
?>
    <div class="catalog">
        <div class="compare">
            <?=$compare_html?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Вообщем ладно...сеть знаний...ничего не не сеть знаний, где люди не разбираются в php, давая поверхностные ответы...
Так так что значит sql inq? то есть кто-то получал доступ путем инъекций?!

Comment: > <?=$vvv['name'], sort($vvv);?>

Это вообще что? 0_о
Что вы хотите сказать это строкой по середине ссылки?

Comment: sort($vvv); исключаем. Сорри..это ошибка

Comment: Лучше отсортировать средствами базы данных, если данные из нее и есть такая возможность.

Comment: сайт на php + mysql

Comment: Пробовал `type_name` не привело к результату.

Comment: А почему собственно сортировка order by? Хорошо что мне написать после order by?

Comment: @JhonnyMnemonik потому что PHP - это черепаха, нет, улитка без кеша. БД сделает это быстрее и, возможно, запомнит.

Comment: @JhonnyMnemonik у вас sqlInjection в коде. вот здесь

    IN (".$in_arr.")

Answer (score 1):

Если сортировать средствами php, то получается примерно так:

```
//объявить ф-цию 1 раз где-нибудь вне циклов
function my_cmp($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a["item_name"], $b["item_name"]);
}
//перед foreach ($itm as $item) { вызывать
usort($itm, "my_cmp");
```

Подробнее: http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php